# Android GooglePlus API ERROR

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I am fetching all the activities from google plus API using [activates.list](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities/list)

**My request:**
    https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/117575809843355974839/activities/public

**Error:**

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
   "domain": "usageLimits",
   "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
   "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
   "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
 ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
   }
}
```

I have authenticated google plus login and getting access token, but how should I use it in making API calls

Comment: You're not actually authenticating there - just configuring for OAuth.Try setting a developer key, that should have tech requests use your project  use createAuthUrl/authenticate to generate an auth URL and exchange the resulting code.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I am using Postman to make API request and I think developer key is not required in fetching activities from google plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an access token you simply need to add `?access_token=[your token]` onto your request.

> https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/117575809843355974839/activities/public?access_token=XXXXX

Background info.  To make any call to Google even to public data you need to identify your application using either an API key (only for public data) or an access token (public and private data).

Comment: @DalmTo It is showing this error

Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

Comment: Then you have not added the access token correctly.  Its not finding there is something wrong with your code

Comment: @DalmTo I am checking using POSTMAN, with correct access token, but it is still not working

Comment: @DalmTo < Continued use requires signup.> This Message

Comment: put the request in a normal web browser I tested it works.  (https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/117575809843355974839/activities/public?access_token=YourToken)   If you are still getting that error its because its not catching the access token.

Comment: @DalmTo What permission are you giving on GoogleSign In? , may be it can be a probelm, I think I am not giving enough permissions??

Comment: This is a public call it shouldn't matter.   The access token I used was actually for Google analytics :o)   Did you try putting it in a web browser ?

Comment: @DalmTo Yes, I have tested it in web broswer too, but it is showing "Unauthenticated"